# Get this paramater url with RewriteRule .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**How can i get only id number after .p?**

sitename.com/keyword.p7145

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.p([0-9]+) index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

This RewriteRule  not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.p(\d+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [END,QSA]
```

Here a somewhat more specific version:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?\w+\.p(\d+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).